# Access 1 property from C# Tuple in Angular2 application using typescript - subscribe data object

Tags: javascript, c#, angular, typescript

I had 2 c# methods doing the exact same thing but return types were different.  So one returned a string and one returned a byte[].  I decided it was messy to have duplicate code and now am trying to change it to one c# method and return a Tuple  which works fine.  Problem is in my angular 2 (typescript)  I subscribe to that method and access data (which used to be a byte[]) but now it's returning the tuple.  So my question is how can I access my data.Item1 (which is the byte array in Angular 2 typescript)

```
this._repService.post(this.connStr + 'api/Report/RenderBoth?id=' + reportUrl + '&format=' +
                    exportType + '', paramArray
                ).subscribe(
                    data => {
                        if (data != null) { // Success
```

Comment: Could you print you the result (`data`)?

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own type.

```
export type MyCustomTuple = [string, number, boolean];

var tuple1: MyCustomTuple = ["string", 1, false]; // OK
// var tuple2: MyCustomTuple = [1, "string", true]; // NOT OK, compile error

console.log(typeof (tuple1[0])); // always string
console.log(typeof (tuple1[1])); // always number
console.log(typeof (tuple1[2])); // always boolean
```

It's kind of a tuple (organized collection of object with different types).